# in Substrate, How to update BabeAuthorityWeight and NextAuthorities from custom pallet?

Tags: rust, substrate, consensus

I would like to customize the POS. I did read some article about how to implement that, and used pallet_babe, my custom pallet and also pallet_staking.

I found that in order to update the authorities for the next block, it is configured in enact_epoch_change() with AuthoritiesId and BabeAuthorityWeight in babe.

However, the target is updating the nextAuthorites, and BabeAuthorityWeight, I I tried with SessionManager to update the validator set for my custom pallet, then assigned the custom pallet SessionManager in pallet_session. But I am not sure how this set would become the nextauthorites in pallet-babe?

Please give me a lead.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Thank you for your question. However it seems like you are not familiar with the guide of Stack Overflow to [How To: Ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Please read it and adjust your question accordingly by using the [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77068047/edit) option. Happy coding!